# Understanding Bug Report in Android Development

Tags: android, debugging, reporting, bug-reporting

I am trying to understand [Bug Reporting](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report) in Android

I successfully Captured the bug reports as mention in [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report) from my Android device

[image]

But don't know how to understand these files, log messages and identify & fix bugs in my App

The documentation also did not go into much detail about it.

Can anyone tell how to understand, identify & fix bugs from Bug Reporting UnZipped Documents or
link any useful Documentation that states the main files in Documents

Comment: Here is Android documentation: https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/read-bug-reports